# Index out of range exception in using ParallelFor loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

This is a very weird situation, first the code...

*The code*

```
 private List<DispatchInvoiceCTNDataModel> WorksheetToDataTableForInvoiceCTN(ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet, int month, int year)
        {
            int totalRows = excelWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
            int totalCols = excelWorksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable(excelWorksheet.Name);
            // for (int i = 1; i <= totalRows; i++)
            Parallel.For(1, totalRows + 1, (i) =>
            {
                DataRow dr = null;
                if (i > 1)
                {
                    dr = dt.Rows.Add();
                }
                for (int j = 1; j <= totalCols; j++)
                {
                    if (i == 1)
                    {
                        var colName = excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString().Replace(" ", String.Empty);
                        lock (lockObject)
                        {
                            if (!dt.Columns.Contains(colName))
                                dt.Columns.Add(colName);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr[j - 1] = excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value != null ? excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString() : null;
                    }
                }
            });
            var excelDataModel = dt.ToList<DispatchInvoiceCTNDataModel>();
            // now we have mapped everything expect for the IDs
            excelDataModel = MapInvoiceCTNIDs(excelDataModel, month, year, excelWorksheet);
            return excelDataModel;
        }
```

*The problem*
When I am running the code on random occasion it would throw `IndexOutOfRangeException` on the line

```
  dr[j - 1] = excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value != null ? excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString() : null;
```

For some random value of `i` and `j`. When I step over the code (`F10`), since it is running in a ParallelLoop, some other thread kicks and and other exception is throw, that other exception is something like (I could not reproduce it, it just came once, but I think it is also related to this threading issue) `Column 31 not found in excelWorksheet`. I don't understand how could any of these exception occur?

*case 1*
The `IndexOutOfRangeException` should not even occur, as the only code/shared variable `dt` I have locked around accessing it, rest all is either local or parameter so there should not have any thread related issue. Also, if I check the value of `i` or `j` in debug window, or even evaluate this whole expression       `dr[j - 1] = excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value != null ? excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString() : null;` or a part of it in Debug window, then it works just fine, no errors of any sort or nothing.

*case 2*
For the second error, (which unfortunately is not reproducing now, but still) it should not have occurred as there are 33 columns in the excel.

*More Code*
In case someone might need how this method was called

```
using (var xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(viewModel.postedFile.InputStream))
            {
                ExcelWorksheets worksheets = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets;

                // other stuff 
                var entities = this.WorksheetToDataTableForInvoiceCTN(worksheets[1], viewModel.Month, viewModel.Year);
                // other stuff 
            }
```

*Other*
If someone needs more code/details let me know.

**Update**
Okay, to answer some comments. It *is* working fine when using `for` loop, I have tested that many times. Also, there is no particular value of `i` or `j` for which the exception is thrown. Sometimes it is `8, 6` at other time it could be anything, say `19,2`or anything. Also, in the `Parallel` loop the `+1` is not doing any damage as the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation says it is exclusive not inclusive. Also, if that were the issue I would only be getting exception at the last index (the last value of i) *but that's not the case*.

**UPDATE 2**
The given answer to lock around the code

```
  dr = dt.Rows.Add();
```

I have changed it to

```
  lock(lockObject) {
      dr = dt.Rows.Add();
  }
```

It is not working. Now I am getting `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, *still* if I run this in debug window, it just works fine.

**Update 3**
Here is the full exception detail, *after update 2* (I am getting this on the line that I mentioned in update 2)

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233086
  Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  Source=mscorlib
  ParamName=index
  StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
       at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
       at System.Data.RecordManager.NewRecordBase()
       at System.Data.DataTable.NewRecordFromArray(Object[] value)
       at System.Data.DataRowCollection.Add(Object[] values)
       at AdminEntity.BAL.Service.ExcelImportServices.<>c__DisplayClass2e.<WorksheetToDataTableForInvoiceCTN>b__2d(Int32 i) in C:\Projects\Manager\Admin\AdminEntity\AdminEntity.BAL\Service\ExcelImportServices.cs:line 578
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClassf`1.<ForWorker>b__c()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Don't work with shared state from `Parallel.For`! `DataTable` is *not* thread-safe.

Comment: @Luaan I have mentioned that I have **put** a lock around it. Also that's not even the problem.

Comment: @mmking: No! As per [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783539(v=vs.110).aspx), it is *exclusive to* not inclusive.

Comment: @mmking: Okay I am adding some updates.

Comment: @mmking: Thanks, but please read and understand the full question before asking/suggesting something.

Comment: You don't have locks everywhere you're accessing the data table - note the `dr = dt.Rows.Add();` with no synchronization whatsoever. In any case, the primary assumption is always that stuff is *not* thread-safe. Have you verified that `ExcelWorksheet` is thread-safe? Also, try using "Break on every exception" rather than stepping through - that might make it easier to reproduce the issue in a debugger. You're losing a whole lot of guarantees when you start doing multi-threading. It's a really complicated problem :)

Comment: Since most of the Parallel code is using the DataTable, you'll need to put a synclock around quite a bit of it. I don't think using Parallel around the DataTable is useful at all, it'll just cause lock contention.

Comment: @Luaan: Since am I only doing a read operation onf `excelWorksheet` is that also required to be thread safe? Even if it's read only?

Comment: You have no idea what it's doing inside. My guess is still that the issue is with the `dt.Rows.Add`, but it's very much possible that `ExcelWorksheet` has an index that it's updating or something like that. Even if you only ever read, it's not guaranteed to be thread-safe, unless it explicitly says so. Maybe it's parsing the data on demand, that's a pretty common pattern for something like that. Maybe it will be enough to read a single cell from the end before the `Parallel.For`, who knows.

Comment: And as vcsjones suggested, just locking around the accesses will pretty much eliminate any parallelism. There's a few ways around that, for example, instead of accessing one common `DataTable`, you could create a part of that datatable on each of the `Parallel` threads, and aggregate them together afterwards. Maybe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Okay.  So there are a few problems with your existing code, most of which have been touched on by others:

- Parallel threads are at the mercy of the OS scheduler; therefore, although threads are queued in-order, they may (and often do) complete execution out-of-order.  For example, given `Parallel.For(0, 10, (i) => { Console.WriteLine(i); });`, the first four threads (on a quad-core system) will be queued with `i` values 0-3.  But any one of those threads may start or finish executing before any other.  So you may see 2 printed first, whereupon thread 4 will be queued.  Then thread 1 might complete, and thread 5 will be queued.  Then thread 4 might complete, even before threads 0 or 3 do.  Etc., etc.  TL;DR: You CANNOT assume an ordered output in parallel.
- Given that, as @ScottChamberlain noted, it's a very bad idea to do column generation within your parallel loop - because you have no guarantee that the thread doing column generation will create all your columns before another thread starts assigning data in rows to those column indices.  E.g. you could be assigning data to cell [0,4] before your table actually has a fifth column.

  - It's worth noting that this should really be broken out of the loop anyway, purely from a code cleanliness perspective.  At the moment, you have two nested loops, each with special behavior on a single iteration; better to separate that setup logic into its own loop and leave the main loop to assign data and nothing else.
- For the same reason, you should not be creating new rows in the table within your parallel loop - because you have no guarantee that the rows will be added to the table in their source order.  Break that out too, and access rows within the loop based on their index.
- Some have mentioned using DataRow.NewRow() before Rows.Add().  *Technically*, NewRow() is the right way to go about things, but the actual recommended access pattern is a bit different than is probably appropriate for a cell-by-cell function, particularly when parallelism is intended (see [MSDN: DataTable.NewRow Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).  The fact remains that adding a new, blank row to a DataTable with Rows.Add() and populating it afterwards functions properly.
- You can clean up your string formatting with the null-coalescing operator `??`, which evaluates whether the preceding value is null, and if so, assigns the subsequent value.  For example, `foo = bar ?? ""` is the equivalent of `if (bar == null) { foo = ""; } else { foo = bar; }`.

So right off the bat, your code should look more like this:

```
private void ReadIntoTable(ExcelWorksheet sheet)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(sheet.Name);
    int height = sheet.Dimension.Rows;
    int width = sheet.Dimension.Columns;

    for (int j = 1; j <= width; j++)
    {
        string colText = (sheet.Cells[1, j].Value ?? "").ToString();
        dt.Columns.Add(colText);
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= height; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add();
    }

    Parallel.For(1, height, (i) =>
    {
        var row = dt.Rows[i - 1];
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            string str = (sheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].Value ?? "").ToString();
            row[j] = str;
        }
    });

    // convert to your special Excel data model
    // ...
}
```

Much better!

...but it still doesn't work!

Yep, it still fails with an IndexOutOfRange exception.  However, since we took your original line `dr[j - 1] = excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value != null ? excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString() : null;` and split it into a couple pieces, we can see exactly which part it fails on.  And it fails on `row[j] = str;`, where we actually write the text into the row.

Uh-oh.

[MSDN: DataRow Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx)

> **Thread Safety**
>
> This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations.

*sigh*.  Yeah.  Who knows why DataRow uses static anything when assigning values, but there you have it; writing to DataRow isn't thread-safe.  And sure enough, doing this...

```
private static object s_lockObject = "";

private void ReadIntoTable(ExcelWorksheet sheet)
{
    // ...
    lock (s_lockObject)
    {
        row[j] = str;
    }
    // ...
}
```

...magically makes it work.  Granted, it completely destroys the parallelism, but it works.

Well, it *almost* completely destroys the parallelism.  Anecdotal experimentation on an Excel file with 18 columns and 46319 rows shows that the Parallel.For() loop creates its DataTable in about 3.2s on average, whereas replacing Parallel.For() with `for (int i = 1; i < height; i++)` takes about 3.5s.  My guess is that, since the lock is only there for writing data, there is a very small benefit realized by writing data on one thread and processing text on the other(s).

Of course, if you can create your own DataTable replacement class, you can see a much larger speed boost.  For example:

```
string[,] rows = new string[height, width];
Parallel.For(1, height, (i) =>
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        rows[i - 1, j] = (sheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].Value ?? "").ToString();
    }
});
```

This executes in about 1.8s on average for the same Excel table mentioned above - about half the time of our barely-parallel DataTable.  Replacing the Parallel.For() with the standard for() in this snippet makes it run in about 2.5s.

So you can see a significant performance boost from parallelism, but also from a custom data structure - although the viability of the latter will depend on your ability to easily convert the returned values to that Excel data model thing, whatever it is.

Comment: Balls! That is lot of *and* a really good explanation. Let me try that and I'll post the update.

Answer (score 6):

The line `dr = dt.Rows.Add();` is not thread safe, you are corrupting the internal state of the array in the DataTable that hold the rows for the table.

At first glance changing it to

```
if (i > 1)
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        dr = dt.Rows.Add();
    }
}
```

should fix it, but that does not mean other thread safety problems are not there from `excelWorksheet.Cells` being accessed from multiple threads. (If `excelWorksheet` is [this class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.aspx) and you are running a STA main thread (WinForms or WPF) COM should marshal the cross thread calls for you)

---

EDIT: New thory, the problem comes from the fact that you are setting up your schema inside the parallel loop and attempting to write to it at the same time. Pull out all of the `i == 1` logic to before the loop and then start at `i == 2`

```
private List<DispatchInvoiceCTNDataModel> WorksheetToDataTableForInvoiceCTN(ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet, int month, int year)
{
    int totalRows = excelWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
    int totalCols = excelWorksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable(excelWorksheet.Name);

    //Build the schema before we loop in parallel.
    for (int j = 1; j <= totalCols; j++)
    {
        var colName = excelWorksheet.Cells[1, j].Value.ToString().Replace(" ", String.Empty);
        if (!dt.Columns.Contains(colName))
            dt.Columns.Add(colName);
    }

    Parallel.For(2, totalRows + 1, (i) =>
    {
        DataRow dr = null;
        lock(lockObject) {
            dr = dt.Rows.Add();
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= totalCols; j++)
        {
            dr[j - 1] = excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value != null ? excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString() : null;
        }
    });
    var excelDataModel = dt.ToList<DispatchInvoiceCTNDataModel>();
    // now we have mapped everything expect for the IDs
    excelDataModel = MapInvoiceCTNIDs(excelDataModel, month, year, excelWorksheet);
    return excelDataModel;
}
```

Comment: Nope! It's not working. Now I am getting `ArguementOutOfRangeException` in *that* line.

Comment: Please show the full exception text, click "[Copy Exception Detail to clipboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/saraford/WindowsLiveWriter/Didyouknowyoucancopytheexceptiondetailsw_F67C/image_2.png)" and paste the text in to your question. Or call `.ToString()` on the thrown exception and write it out somewhere on the disk where you can copy and paste it.

Comment: Its got to be the `dr[j - 1] = ...` messing it up. You will need to make thread local DataTables and merge them when done.

Comment: Okay, it *might* be this. But *how?* I mean seriously? isn't it local to each thread?

Comment: As I was writing up the how and I think I stumbled on the real problem. If this does not solve it I will show you how to clone and merge the tables.

Comment: Thanks for update, but it is *still* not working. Getting the same exception `ArguementOutOfRangeException` in the same line `dr[j-1] = ...`

Comment: Browsing through msdn lead me to the Remarks section of the DataTable class page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx it explicitly says that to create a new row one should use the NewRow() method, and once the row is ready then use the .Rows.Add() method to store it in the DataTable. Your use of .Rows.Add() may work in some cases, but it's not the documented way - and it may then not guarantee thread safety.

Answer (score 3):

You code is incorrect:

1) Parallel.For has its own batching mechanism (can be customized with ForEach with partitioners though) and does not guarantee that operation with (for) i==n will be executed after operation with i==m where n>m.
So line

```
dr[j - 1] = excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value != null ? excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString() : null;
```

throw exception when required column is not added yet (in {i==1} operation}

2) And it's recommended to use NewRow method:

```
dr=tbl.NewRow->Populate dr->tbl.Rows.Add(dr)
```

or Rows.Add(object[] values):

```
values=[KnownColumnCount]->Populate values->tbl.Rows.Add(values)
```

3) It's really better to populate columns first in this case, because it's sequential access to excel file (seek) and It would not harm perfomance

Comment: Thanks, I understand your 2nd and 3rd point, but can you please elaborate a little on the first point? Perhaps add a little more explanation? Specifically the line `does not guarantee that n operation will be executed after m (even partially) if n>m.`

Comment: I mean that order of the iterations is not guaranteed. You cannot assume any specific order. Doing so will lead to unpredictable results (like you case for ex). Some iterations may be executed in one thread, some - not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using NewRow when creating the new datarow and moving the creation of the columns outside the parallel loop like Scott Chamberlain suggested above? By using newrow you're creating a row with the same schema as the parent datatable. I got the same error as you when I tried your code with a random excel file, but got it to work like this:

```
            for (int x = 1; x <= totalCols; x++)
        {
            var colName = excelWorksheet.Cells[1, x].Value.ToString().Replace(" ", String.Empty);

            if (!dt.Columns.Contains(colName))
                dt.Columns.Add(colName);

        }

        Parallel.For(2, totalRows + 1, (i) =>
        {
            DataRow dr = null;

            for (int j = 1; j <= totalCols; j++)
            {
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[j - 1] = excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value != null
                    ? excelWorksheet.Cells[i, j].Value.ToString()
                    : null;
                lock (lockObject)
                {
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
        });
```